# Spring Resfull error HTTP Status 500

Tags: spring-mvc

I try to build spring restfull services tutorial, and this is my code :

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>accounts</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/mvc-config.xml
                /WEB-INF/app-config.xml
            </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>accounts</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

and this is my controller:

```
@Controller
public class AccountController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/accounts", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {"application/json"})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public List<Account> accountSummary() {
        return accountManager.getAllAccounts();
    }
}
```

When I open browser with url : `http://localhost:8080/rest-ws/app/accounts`
I got this error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [accounts]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/rest-ws/app/accounts] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)
```

What does I miss ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/accounts")
public class AccountController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/list", 
         method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {"application/json"})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public List<Account> accountSummary() {
         return accountManager.getAllAccounts();
    }
}
```

Open:

```
http://localhost:8080/rest-ws/app/accounts/list
```

It worked?

Comment: I have researched and I find that I miss @ReponseBody, thanks